# Recompile main-file automatically after every compile of other files

Tags: compiling, automation, command-line

I am using [Kile](https://kile.sourceforge.io/) as LaTeX editor (great btw). For the pictures I use a standalone class and include the resulting .pdf via `\includegraphics`.

However, when I change my graphic and compile it in the standalone-file, I have to search manually for my main-file and recompile this also.

After a few times this is getting frustrating. Can I just say, in any way, that whenever any file in my project is changed, it should automatically start a recompilation of the main? So I don't have to search everytime for my main file.

Comment: The handling of depedancies is usualy handled by make or more tex oriented utilities like texmaker. But it works in the opposite direction. I doubtt of the pertinence of this worklow. For example, il you work on an external tikz file, you likely dont need to compile the whole main for each complitation cycle of hte figure. If you really want that, you can use a bash script where the two compilation are linked with a && on the command line. Anoter option (not tested) could be a shell escape at the end of the figure file (with afterhipout hook) but at the risk to create infinite loops.

Comment: duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448195/change-directory-using-pdflatex-in-command-line