# Change directory using PDFLatex in command line

Tags: compiling

I want pdflatex to just run

```
pdflatex 'current_file'.tex
```

And then afterwards compile my main.tex which is in another directory. So to make my realtive paths working I have to use a change directory command like 'cd'.

Using a normald shell in windows work when I say

```
 pdflatex 'current_file'.tex && cd home/tex/ && pdflatex main
```

However, in Kile this did not work. Is it somehow possible as I can just configure the pure Pdflatex command. Is it possible to add in its arguments something like a change directory so to have:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode 'change directory command' file
```

?

Comment: can't you just do `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory='/path/to the/new/' '/path/to the/new/file.tex'` ?

Comment: oh wow that works. i was thinking this command just provide a new path as i already tried pdflatex 'path-to-directory'_filename and this failed as the current directoy is still the wrong one. but your code is working fine

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `-output-directory` argument of pdflatex, like so:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory='/path/to the/new/' '/path/to the/new/file.tex'
```